# jQuery-File-Upload, How can use two forms to upload files?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I know how to use plugin jQuery-File-Upload for one form.
but How can I use it for two forms?
 I try to change the id of the forms, upload-template-id, and download-template-id

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" action="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-upload-template-id="template-upload-1" data-download-template-id="template-download-1">
          ...      
 </form>


<form id="fileupload2" method="POST" action="video" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-upload-template-id="template-upload-2"
                  data-download-template-id="template-download-2">
          ...
 </form>

<script id="template-download-1" type="text/x-tmpl">
        ...
</script>
<script id="template-download-2" type="text/x-tmpl">
        ...
</script>
```

but only the first from display the result

So, How can I use two different forms to upload files with jQuery-File-Upload?